# Rigify Not working correctly

Tags: rigging

I am completely new to Rigify and I am following a video tutorial to learn it.

At this point everything looks fine.

[image]

but when I hit the *Generate Rig* button this happens:

[image]

Can anyone help me fix this?

Comment: the origins of the mesh and the metarig should be in the same place. It's the little orange dot when you select it, as shown in the screenshot above. Select the mesh and apply the *Location* (Ctrl+A). Do the same with the metarig. The origins are then at the world origin (0, 0, 0). Also make sure you have applied to *Scale* to the metarig.

Comment: "the origins of the mesh and the metarig should be in the same place. It's the little orange dot when you select it, as shown in the screenshot above. Select the mesh and apply the Location (Ctrl+A). Do the same with the metarig. The origins are then at the world origin (0, 0, 0). Also make sure you have applied to Scale to the metarig" - This was it. This was assumed in the video. Easy mistake to make. Thank you